# How to Create a new culture assembly WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, multilingual, globalization

I am Following a tutorial on [implementing localization in my Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37339/WPF-Localization?msg=5046529#xx5046529xx).

But i cant get my head around step 4, where he says to create a new culture assembly.

> The loaded Assemblies ResourceDictionaries will be used to replace the default one within the main Assembly.
>
> 1. Create normal WPF App, and use a `ResourceDictionary` for strings
> 2. Use `MergedDictionary` in `App.resources`
> 3. Make sure any localizable controls using a `DynamicResource` like
>      `<Label Content=”{DynamicResource label1}”/>`
> 4. **Create a new culture assembly with a sensible name, such as Culture_fr-CA**
> 5. For assembly created in step 4, create mirror image `ResourceDictionary` that matches the original Assemblies `ResourceDictionary`. but with translated strings
> 6. Compile the culture assembly to some folder under main Assemblies bin\debug folder. This demo assumes this folder is called “CultureFiles”
> 7. When main app runs, get current culture and Load the matching Assembly from disk
> 8. From the currently loaded Culture Assembly, extract the `ResourceDictionary`
> 9. Using the extracted `ResourceDictionary`, replace the current `Application.MergedResources` dictionary with the newly extracted culture `ResourceDictionary`
> 10. All controls that refer to the Dynamic resources should be ok now with new cultural strings

Comment: When asking a question on Stack Overflow, please include enough information so we can answer your question without having to read through the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it just means you add an extra WPF project to your solution. They add the name of the culture to the project's name.